# Facebook iOS AppInvite skip composing message

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I can show an AppInvite dialog simply by following the instruction [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios). However, I have a requirement that when AppInvite dialog is initiated, it should not let user enter a message, but rather go straight to the list of friends to send invitations to. The invite message can be blank or pre-filled by the app.

Is this possible with the latest (v4) Facebook SDK?

Comment: You are not allowed to pre-fill the message via your app, and you can not prevent the user from entering their own message either.

Comment: @CBroe , do you have a reference for that? I know of at least one app that skips the message field and instead provides a default message, but that was a while ago, so is it possible that this is a new requirement by Facebook?